# Someone's laughing stock

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, idioms, expressions

Imagine someone is so silly or behaves so stupidly or often says so foolish stuff that makes him sound ridiculous.
I wonder how can one mention such a person?

I know the term "laughing stock" that according to the dictionary definition means:

> **[Laughing stock:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+laughing+stock)** 
> A person who is the subject of mockery after a blunder.

- If I mess up this speech, I'll be the laughing stock of the school!

Would it make sense to tell a close friend smilingly:

> - (1) **He's our laughing stock.** [Meaning: someone who we laugh at in our company - like an inside joke]

or

> - (2) **This matter has become the laughing stock for all.** [Meaning: something that everyone finds it  silly and hilarious  that whenever thinks about it.]

If no, then how shall I refer to them?

Answer (score 1):

> He’s our laughing stock

This sentence doesn’t really flow so *He’s our laughing stock* is wrong. You **can’t be some particular person’s laughing stock**, you can only be a laughing stock for everyone. Take this example sentence:

> Since he failed his examination, he’s definitely going to be a **laughing stock**.

> This matter has become the laughing stock for all

This sentence does not flow too.
Only a person can become a laughing stock.
Take the example which I wrote previously:

> Since he failed his examination, he’s definitely going to be a **laughing stock**.

The he refers to a person , so laughing stock only refers to **a person**

Comment: Thank you @Genie. So can I say: "He's a laughing stock **for me**" instead of the case #1? I wonder what would you say rather than the second case?

Comment: @A-friend No. As I’ve said in the answer above, you can’t be somebody’s particular laughing stock, you can only be a laughing stock for somebody. You can’t write “He’s a laughing stock for me.” You can write “He’s a laughing stock for everyone. “

Comment: That's not entirely accurate, Genie. Collins Dictionary gives the example _His policies became the laughing stock of the financial community._

Comment: @KateBunting the **financial community** means that it is the **full community**.

Comment: @Genie - You claimed that 'only a person can become a laughing stock' - and 'the financial community' is only a section of the community at large.

Comment: Thank you @kate Bunting. That said, I was wondering what expression / idiom / word can be used instead when I am going to refer to someone else as "**my**" laughing stock as this term can not be utilized for a particular person.

Also, I guess a laughing stock only refers to "**a person**" not a thing. If so, I wonder what should I use instead.

Comment: If only you find the person funny,  you can only say that they seem ridiculous to you or make you laugh. The quotation I found in Collins (above) shows that a laughing stock does not _have_ to be a person.